# SAXParser and XMLReader android - unable to read certain tags that end /> instead of </tag-name>

Tags: android, xml-parsing, tags, saxparser

**Background:**

Working on an application that retrieves information from a website. This was an application I worked on a few months ago, and back then everything was fine, but I'm back for maintenance and to continue the project.

**What am I retrieving:**

view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=news/latest_news.rss

Please view the source to see the XML. Please notice that every item has category, link, pubDate, title, description and guid. And only a few items have enclosures.

**Problem:**

Every tag starts with < tag > and ends with < / tag > except enclosures, which end with / >, and this is what's messing up the reading process, but I'm not sure how to account for it, or if its well formed XML.

**Question:**

Is there anyway to handle tags that don't end in the conventional < / tag > way?

*Below is ALL the code I have so far* - If anyone has any questions, please feel free to ask. Thank you fellow stackoverflow-ers for any help or comments, its appreciated.

**How I process it:**

I use SAXParserFactory and XML Reader:

```
            try 
            {
                /** Handling XML */
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
                URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://services.runescape.com/m=news/latest_news.rss");
                /**
                 * Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends
                 * DefaultHandler )
                 */
                //MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(new MyXMLHandler());
                xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.i("EXCEPTION:","HomeActivity.java, line 121 - xml not parsed");
            }
            /** Get result from MyXMLHandler XMLlist Object */
            newsList = MyXMLHandler.xMLList;
```

**Global variable:**

```
private XMLList newsList;
```

**XMLList class:**

I display the news "items" by retrieving the lists from all the get methods in XMLList class.

So if there are 15 items, there should be 15 dates, categories, links, etc. but with the enclosure problem, it starts enclosures but doesn't end them.

So I get 15 titles but only 12 dates, 12 categories, 12 links etc. If you search the word "enclosure" in the source for the rss above (view-source:http://services.runescape.com/m=news/latest_news.rss), you will see only 3 items have enclosures.

```
public class XMLList
{

/** Variables */
private ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String>  detail = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();
/**
 * In Setter method default it will return arraylist change that to add
 */

public XMLList()
{
    title.clear();
    detail.clear();
    description.clear();
    link.clear();
    date.clear();
    category.clear();
}
public ArrayList<String> getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String name)
{
    this.title.add(name);
}
public ArrayList<String> getDetail()
{
    return detail;
}
public void setDetail(String detail)
{
    this.detail.add(detail);
}
public ArrayList<String> getDescription()
{
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description)
{
    this.description.add(description);
}
public void setLink(String link)
{
    this.link.add(link);
}
public ArrayList<String> getLink()
{
    return link;
}
public void setDate(String date)
{
    this.date.add(date);
}
public ArrayList<String> getDate()
{
    return date;
}
public void setCategory(String cat)
{
    this.category.add(cat);
}
public ArrayList<String> getCategory()
{
    return category;
}
}
```

**MyXMLHandler class:**

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
public static XMLList xMLList;
Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;

Boolean inTitle = false;
Boolean inDescription = false;
Boolean inItem = false;
Boolean inDate = false;
Boolean inLink = false;
Boolean inCategory = false;

StringBuilder buff = null;

public MyXMLHandler()
{
    xMLList = new XMLList();
}
// All methods auto called in this order - start, characters, end
/*
 * Called when an xml tag starts
 * imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
 */
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
{
    if(xMLList == null)
    {
        xMLList = new XMLList();
    }
    if(localName.equals("item"))
    {
        inItem = true;
    }
    if (inItem) 
    {
        Log.d("START " + localName,"");
        if (localName.equals("title")) 
        {
            inTitle = true;
            buff = new StringBuilder();
        }
        if (localName.equals("description")) 
        {
            inDescription = true;
            buff = new StringBuilder();
        }
        if (localName.equals("link")) 
        {
            inLink = true;
            buff = new StringBuilder();
        }
        if (localName.equals("pubDate")) 
        {
            inDate = true;
            buff = new StringBuilder();
        }
        if (localName.equals("category")) 
        {
            inCategory = true;
            buff = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}
/*
 * Called when an xml tag ends
 */
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException
{
    if (inItem && !inTitle && !inDescription && !inLink && !inDate && !inCategory) 
    {
        Log.d("END ITEM", "");
        inItem = false;
    } 
    else if (inTitle) 
    {
        String check = buff.toString().trim();
        Log.d("TITLE:", check);
        Log.d("END " + localName,"");
        xMLList.setTitle(check);
        inTitle = false;
        buff = null;
    }
    else if (inDescription) 
    {
        String check  = buff.toString().trim();
        Log.d("DESC:", check);
        Log.d("END " + localName,"");
        xMLList.setDescription(check);
        inDescription = false;
        buff = null;
    }
    else if (inLink) 
    {
        String check  = buff.toString().trim();
        Log.d("LINK:", check);
        Log.d("END " + localName,"");
        xMLList.setLink(check);
        inLink = false;
        buff = null;
    }
    else if (inDate) 
    {
        String check  = buff.toString().trim();
        Log.d("DATE:", check);
        Log.d("END " + localName,"");
        check = check.substring(0,16);
        xMLList.setDate(check);
        inDate = false;
        buff = null;
    }
    else if(inCategory)
    {
        String check  = buff.toString().trim();
        Log.d("CATEGORY:", check);
        Log.d("END " + localName,"");
        xMLList.setCategory(check);
        inCategory = false;
        buff = null;
    }
}

/*
 * Called to get tag characters
 */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException
{
    if (buff != null) 
    {
        for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++) 
        {
            buff.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `endElement` method you have:

```
    if (inItem && !inTitle && !inDescription && !inLink && !inDate && !inCategory)
    {
        Log.d("END ITEM", "");
        inItem = false;
    }
```

This is setting `inItem` to false when the parser hits an `<enclosure />` tag.

You should only set `inItem` to false when you actually encounter an `</item>` end tag, which will be detected by hitting `endElement` with a `localname` of "item".

Your use of multiple lists in the XMLList class is also quite fragile.  You would be better off creating class with fields matching the tags you're reading and building a single list of objects of that class.

Comment: Working on it now, what you're saying does make sense :),  And thanks for the advice on the XMLList class, I worked on this a while ago and I can definitely improve it.